# My grpc server is having slower response after a few hours

Tags: c#, performance, service, grpc, response

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/458B1.png)
I added one line log to monitor Perform function and it seems runtime is always around 1ms. However, after a few hours grpc logger shows the response time is very high. It will print out something like:

```
Request finished HTTP/2 POST http://127.0.0.1:5060/Instrument.InstrumentControl/Perform application/grpc - - 200 - application/grpc 9.9647ms
```

If I leave the service on for a few days, this number will go up to 170ms, but my log still shows my function still takes about 1ms. The client side is also laggy at this point.
Can anyone please tell me where the overhead is? Thanks in advance!

Consistent runtime from grpc logging.

my code:

```
public class Program
{
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(opt =>
                        {
                            opt.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                        });
                    });
                    webBuilder.UseUrls($"http://[::]:{ServicePort.InstrumentService}");
                });

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
}

public class Startup
{            
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {          
            services.AddGrpc().AddServiceOptions<InstrumentService>(options =>
            {
                options.MaxReceiveMessageSize = Data.Constants.GrpcMaxLength.MaxMsgRecLen;
                options.MaxSendMessageSize = Data.Constants.GrpcMaxLength.MaxMsgRecLen;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
               
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<InstrumentService>();
              
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<SubscribeService>();

                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

InstrumentService are all Unary RPC.
SubscribeService is a single server streaming rpc which is active as long as client is connected and it publishes data/status back to client. My current usage is single client with the service.

Client side:

```
public static GrpcChannel CreateChannel(string ip, int port)
        {
            return GrpcChannel.ForAddress($"http://{ip}:{port}",
                new GrpcChannelOptions
                {
                    HttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
                    {
                        PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
                        EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true,
                    },
                    DisposeHttpClient = true,
                    MaxReceiveMessageSize = 
                    Constants.GrpcMaxLength.MaxMsgRecLen,
                    MaxSendMessageSize = 
                    Constants.GrpcMaxLength.MaxMsgSndLen
                }
            );
        }
_channel = CreateChannel(config.Ip, config.port);

_instrumentClient = new InstrumentControl.InstrumentControlClient(_channel);

_subscribeClient = new SubscribeControl.SubscribeControlClient(_channel);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add the code of the endpoint and other relevant pieces of it? This makes it easier to analyse your problem.